# insert autoincrement into second column

Tags: mysql, auto-increment

I am looking to do a query like so:

id | int | autoincrement
something | varchar | 255

```
insert into `table` set something = concat('val', id);
```

so that the table ends up looking like

> 1|val1
>   2|val2
>   3|val3...

except that id always ends up being `val0` for every row.

How can I do this?

Comment: Why do you need to do this?

Wouldn't a view like

    SELECT id,concat('val',id) as FldName FROM table

work for you?

Comment: this is an overly simplified example, val is actually a code, so the actual function call is `concat('1234',id,'567')` (with 1234 and 567 being different values of different lengths each time).

I am basically asking, how can I get the insert_id in the same query.

Comment: I think you would have to do an UPDATE Trigger AFTER INSERT to retrieve the new ID.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
mysql> describe concattest;
+-------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id    | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| val   | text             | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO concattest (val) VALUES (concat('val', LAST_INSERT_ID()));
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.06 sec)

mysql> select * from concattest;
+----+------+
| id | val  |
+----+------+
|  1 | val0 |
+----+------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO concattest (val) VALUES (concat('val', LAST_INSERT_ID()));
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from concattest;
+----+------+
| id | val  |
+----+------+
|  1 | val0 |
|  2 | val1 |
+----+------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO concattest (val) VALUES (concat('val', LAST_INSERT_ID()));
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from concattest;
+----+------+
| id | val  |
+----+------+
|  1 | val0 |
|  2 | val1 |
|  3 | val2 |
+----+------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: you can also to LAST_INSERT_ID()+1 :) so val1 appears instead of val0

Comment: This also assumes that the application is still using the same db connection

Comment: but would LAST_INSERT_ID not be 0 on the first insert of a connection?

Comment: This also assumes that no concurrent insertion took place in between.

Comment: This **WON'T WORK** in general.  LAST_INSERT_ID() is returning the *previously-inserted* autoincrement value on the current DB connection.  This will not generally be the id key of the last row of the table you're currently inserting into:  As @Hailwood says, for a new connection it will always be 0.  It may also be a key from an entirely different table, if there was a previous insert to that table (which is what @ RandomSeed means I think).