# How to make second column increament if one column is already auto increament?

Tags: mysql

I have three column(ID,Receipt_no,Name) in my table.ID is primary key auto increment so ID will start from 1, Same think i have to set on receipt_no so it will also start from 1.Is it possible?

I am using phpmyadmin.

Thanks in advance.

```
-- Table structure for table `temp`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `temp` (
`Id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Receipt_no` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Name` varchar(20) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;


ALTER TABLE `temp`
 ADD PRIMARY KEY (`Id`), ADD UNIQUE KEY `Receipt_no` (`Receipt_no`);

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for dumped tables
--

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for table `temp`
--
ALTER TABLE `temp`
MODIFY `Id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
```

Comment: No.  Only one auto increment column per tale.

Comment: Sure. Use my sequence number thingie [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38079598) and fetch your next num for that non-`AUTO_INCREMENT` column. You have it, use it on the insert for the non AI column. Is it easy? No. No one said programming was always easy.

Comment: Means i have to set receipt_no unique key?can you help me with simple query?

Comment: Do you want me to show you a full working demo with one auto_inc and one other incrementing number (let's say it starts at 1000)? But only if you can write stored procs (save them I mean) via PHPMyAdmin.

Comment: Mr.Drew, I added table structure..If possible please share demo.

Comment: You may be able to set up a trigger to do so.  Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15388098/auto-increment-second-column  for ideas.

Comment: @TimDearborn that is a custom prefix concat to match the autoinc id

Comment: Sorry Mr.Tim i tried that code but i am getting zero value in receipt no.

Comment: If you want the `receipt_no` to equal `id` always, then don't even have a `receipt_no`.

Comment: Ok Mr. Drew,, Can we start receipt_no from 100?

Comment: You can specify the first value for auto increment, so you don't have to start at 1.

Comment: Mr.Arjan, I have one primary key auto increment and i have to set same on second column.

Answer (score 1):

Create a db for safe testing:

```
create schema Hybreeder;
use Hybreeder;
```

Schema:

```
CREATE TABLE `temp` (
    `Id` int(11) AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    `Receipt_no` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `Name` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
    UNIQUE KEY `unq_Receipt_no` (`Receipt_no`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

-- The following table would be useful system wide for all
-- your special incrementor needs whatever they may be
-- Especially great for those looking for Prefixes to
-- add to PK's like an id such as ABC00001
create table sequences
(   id int auto_increment primary key,
    sectionType varchar(200) not null,
    nextSequence int not null,
    unique key(sectionType)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

-- Prime it with some "sections" (we had to call them something)
insert sequences (sectionType,nextSequence) values
('Chassis',1),('Engine Block',1),('Carburetor',1),('Receipt',1001);
```

Stored Proc:

```
DROP PROCEDURE if exists getNextSequence;
DELIMITER $$ -- Note: delete this line for PHPMyAdmin (you don't need it)
CREATE PROCEDURE getNextSequence(p_sectionType varchar(200))
BEGIN
    -- pass in as a parameter the "section" for next inc, such as "Chassis"
    START TRANSACTION;
    SELECT nextSequence into @mine_to_use from sequences where sectionType=p_sectionType FOR UPDATE;
    UPDATE sequences set nextSequence=nextSequence+1 where sectionType=p_sectionType;
    COMMIT; -- get and release INTENTION LOCK ASAP
    SELECT @mine_to_use as yourSeqNum; -- return as a 1 column, 1 row resultset
END;
$$ -- Note: delete this line for PHPMyAdmin (you don't need it)
DELIMITER ; -- Note: delete this line for PHPMyAdmin (you don't need it)
```

Your client program will call the stored proc and process the result set getting the next num to use such as:

```
call getNextSequence("Receipt");
+------------+
| yourSeqNum |
+------------+
|       1001 |
+------------+
```

call it again for the heck of it:

```
call getNextSequence("Receipt");
+------------+
| yourSeqNum |
+------------+
|       1002 |
+------------+
```

It now has a 1 row 1 column result set with the column name `yourSeqNum`.

Let's pseudocode call that `NNNNN` as a variable.

```
INSERT temp(`Receipt_no`,`Name`) VALUES (NNNNN,'Fred'); -- again this is pseudocode
```

`Id` is the `AUTO_INCREMENT` column so we skip it in the column list above. It gets dealt with automatically by MySQL.

Why is it pseudocode? Because there is no talk here about what your front-end language is such as PHP, Python, Java, to know how you processed that result set to get the variable `NNNNN`. And I am not writing everything!

Your task for all that follow is to merely tweek the part above that gets that sequence number into a variable and use it in the `INSERT` statement.

Cleanup:

```
DROP SCHEMA Hybreeder;
```

Now there are those that would say this whole thing looks silly, for `NNNNN` is always 1000 greater than `Id` so what is the point? If you had multiple consumers of the sequence table for the receipt section, say other processes or other companies, then that would not be the case.

Please follow along the narrative over [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38079598) for more technical aspects that I glossed over above.